# Issues with Achievements Dropdown

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

[image]
[image]

In the first image it shows +8, and it should be +33. The second shows +37 and it should be +111.

Why am I getting these big differences?

Comment: Not sure how this is related to sockets? The number is also being reset when you click it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is it not related to sockets? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168145/sockets-used-by-stack-overflow I know it's reset, but see the blue highlited ones, those are ones I've not seen yet, and they don't add to the total in the green bubble

Comment: If you mean that after page reload the number is correct then you're right, but I assumed you mean the number is wrong even after a reload - and that's not related to web sockets in such case. (as far as I know - the sockets are just used to *update* the number, not give the initial state)

Comment: In the first screenshot, you got `+5` and `+3` on those two posts for three new votes (up vote on one, up- and down vote on the other). There previous `+15` and `+10` already earned for the posts did not count for the *change* in points.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ahh, so it's bundling together but the alert gives only the new stuff. I see

Comment: It is **not** the sum of the votes on the highlighted entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlighted entries received votes, and those votes in total changed your reputation by the amount shown in green.

That does **not** mean that all points earned for the highlighted entries are summed to form the change in reputation shown in green, it just means that those entries where voted on.

In the first screenshot for example, you received an up-vote on one question and an up- and a down-vote on the other. Those questions *already* hand gained you +15 and +5 points respectively, but now you gained another +8 (2 * +5 + 1 * -2) in reputation.

In the intervening time between the first and second screenshot, more things happened, including an up-vote being *removed* (-10 points), replaced with a down-vote (-2 points), another had 4 upvotes and a downvote yesterday (+38) with the downvote converted to an upvote the next day (+12), and you got an upvote on your Meta question (+5). That makes a change in reputation of +38 points, presumably you downvoted something to account for the remaining `-1` but removed that down-vote since.