# How does Stack Exchange's back-end communicate with its front-end?

Tags: discussion

During the day I usually leave a Stack Overflow page open on one of my screens. While I'm working on another screen I can see whenever the question or an answer is voted on immediately, and I get message alerts whenever someone answers or replies to one of my posts immediately as well.

I was just wondering how this is accomplished without having to refresh the page. Is the browser constantly communicating with some server in the background? I really like this feature and want to know more about how it works.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Comet (Web Application Model)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)), specifically [AJAX with Long Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Ajax_with_long_polling)

Comment: @MatiCicero Thanks, I'll look into those

Comment: I think SO uses [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) for real-time notifications though (which is another technology). SO has the domain [sockets.stackexchange.com](http://sockets.stackexchange.com) for establishing web socket connections. You'll get a **502 Bad Gateway** if you go there because you can't connect to a websocket using `http:` protocol, you need to use `ws:` (unsecure) or `wss:` (secure)

Comment: @MatiCicero Not socket.io, just websockets. We don't use node.js on Q&A sites.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168148/254554

Comment: @AnnaLear you don't use node... "on Q&A sites"? Does SE use node.js somewhere?

Comment: @nhinkle For running some scripts during builds. We used to have a node-based project, but switched back to C# now. There may be some in internal tools, but I don't know for sure off the top of my head.